# My co-workers left me a message

Tags: riddle, knowledge, computer-puzzle

While refactoring a massive chunk of old code, I found a rather curious section of code commented out that wasn't there the day before. Can you tell me what it means?

```
bool YoureObviouslyUpset = true;
try { int TO = 2; }
catch (MismatchException ME) {
    if (YoureObviouslyUpset)
        CaptureAllNegativity();
}
```

Comment: Realised my answer was missing something and added it on.

Comment: The similarity between the [puzzling.se] logo and the [workplace.se] logo is even more confusing with a title like that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Is the message:

> "Try To Catch Me If You Can"?

Because:

> The boolean variable and function have the initials YOU and CAN, and then there is a TRY on the variable TO with an exception CATCH for ME then an IF statement on the boolean YOU, which executes the function CAN if true, which it is.

Answer (score 3):

```
try { int TO = 2; }
catch {
```

> // this is what we do if we can't put 2 and TO together.

```
}
```

Comment: very funny +1!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking the answer is:

> If you're unhappy also, and you're obviously upset (about something), so we need to talk about it and deal with it.
> Presumably the author is upset about something that happened at work, sees that you are upset about it as well, and wants to talk to you about it to see if the hard feelings can be resolved.

Reasoning:

> int TO = 2; // TO => ticked off, 2 => too (or also)
>  catch (MismatchException ME)  // 2 as too is a string, so a string assigned to an int would be an exception, so catch ME (as in find me)
>  //  MismatchException could also mean that the author and the reader clashed over something, or said differently, their opinions mismatched.
>  if (YoureObviouslyUpset)  // YoureObviouslyUpset was set to true previously
>  CaptureAllNegativity();  // method call, essentially meaning  "let's go somewhere else and talk about this"

Comment: `int TO = 2;` is valid, it is assigning an integer to a variable named "TO"